# "A subdirectory of file txt already exists." error when trying to sort files, even though there are no files name "txt"

Tags: python, shutil

I'm trying to make a python script that moves all files with a specific extension into respective folders, which are named with the extension, like TXT. However, upon running the code it comes up with the error "A subdirectory of file txt already exists." but after looking in the folder that has the files that need to be sorted, there hasn't even been a file created with such name.

```py
import os
import shutil

try:
    path = "/Users/name/Desktop/test2/"
    for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            extension=file.split('.')[1]
            print(extension)
            if os.path.exists(r"/Users/name/Desktop/test2/" +extension):
                if file.endswith(extension):
                    shutil.move(file, "/Users/name/Desktop/test2/" +extension)
            else:
                os.system('mkdir ' + extension)
                shutil.move(file, "/Users/name/Desktop/test2/" +extension)
except:
    print("done")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Just a minor nit.  Use a different variable for your main path like ```main_path = "/Users/name/Desktop/test2/"```, mainly because you're going to get that value overwritten within the for loop.  that said, please post the full traceback.

Comment: I tried that but it still comes up with the same error, also what do you mean by the full traceback?

Comment: @CommandBlock The error message starts with `Traceback (most recent call last): ...`

Comment: @CommandBlock Question: Why don't you use `os.makedir(s)` to create new directories? Could it be that `os.system('mkdir ' + extension)` is a problem? Seems to me that it only works as intended if the `cwd` is `/Users/name/Desktop/test2/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import os
import shutil

try:
    root = '/Users/name/Desktop/test2/'
    for path, _, files in os.walk(root):
        for file in files:
            extension = file.split('.')[1]
            path_ext = os.path.join(root, extension)
            os.makedirs(path_ext, exist_ok=True)
            path_file = os.path.join(path, file)
            shutil.move(path_file, path_ext)
except:
    print('done')
```

`os.path.join()` is a safer way to construct paths. As mentioned in my comment I would use the `os.makedirs()` to create paths.

Comment: This works perfectly, but the .txt files don't go into the folder.

Comment: @CommandBlock That's strange? It worked in my small test environment with several extensions,   including txt.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating the txt file in your working directory rather than in the directory referenced by you path variable.  You need to add the path before each time you reference the filename or the directory name.

```
import os
import shutil

try:
    path = "/Users/name/Desktop/test2/"
    for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            extension=file.split('.')[1]
            print(extension)
            if os.path.exists(path +extension):
                print('not exist')
                if file.endswith(extension):
                    print(file)
                    shutil.move(path + file, path +extension)
            else:
                print('exists')
                print(file)

                os.system('mkdir ' + path + extension)
                shutil.move(path + file, path +extension)
except:
    print("done")
```

Comment: I tried this, and it seems to work as intended, however, instead of making a folder, it makes a "file" no extension, no nothing. I can't access this "file" either.

Comment: What is `wpath` here?

Comment: Oops, sorry.  I initially used wpath as the user set path variable so it wouldn't be overwritten by os.walk but I removed it because it was unnecessary.